# How to do Redis slave repalication in k8s cluster?

Tags: redis, kubernetes, cluster-computing, replication, master-slave

By this famous guestbook example:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/guestbook

It will create Redis master/slave deployment and services. It also has a subfolder named `redis-slave` which used for create a docker image and run Redis replication command.

- Dockerfile
- run.sh

The question is, if deployed the Redis master and slave to the k8s cluster. Then how to run that command? Deploy a new container? That will not relate to the slave container already deployed.

Is there a better way to do Redis repliaciton between master and slave running in k8s cluster?

Comment: which command you mean? The run.sh command is the entrypoint of the redis-slave container, so when you create the redis-slave deployment on kubernetes, that command will run.

Comment: @fiunchinho I have found that use the `redis-slave-deployment.yaml` has already included that shell command. So just deploy that manifest will be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is using `helm` to deploy the `redis-ha` app.

Info about helm: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm

The `redis-ha` helm app page: https://hub.kubeapps.com/charts/stable/redis-ha

Comment: I have another question that how can I found the `host` and `port` if use this way to install redis? Because I should connect to the redis host from application.

Comment: Is the client application inside or outside kubernetes?

Comment: Inside the Kubernetes cluster. It will connect to redis in the same cluster.

Comment: Good, you have to use the service endpoint then. Run `kubectl -n <namespace> get svc`. From that list, there should be a service that points your redis cluster. You can use the service name in the format `<service name>.<namespace>` as the hostname to reach your redis cluster

Comment: My pleasure to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Redis [Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) is often suggested for simple master-slave replication and high availability.

Unfortunately, Sentinel does not fit Kubernetes world well and it also requires a Sentinel-aware client to talk to Redis.

You could try [Redis operator](https://github.com/amaizfinance/redis-operator) which can be considered a Kubernetes-native replacement for Sentinel and allows to create a Redis deployment that would resist without human intervention to most kind of failures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can setup Redis HA Master Slave Cluster in Kubernetes/Openshift OKD

Basically you have to use configMap, StatefulSet in collaboration with VolumeClaims

https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/10/01/redis-ha-master-slave-cluster-up-and-running-in-openshift-okd-kubernetes/